# ListPlot3D: generating mesh lines at hard-coded locations

Tags: plotting, mesh

I am plotting a surface specified with a set of `{x,y,z}` coordinates with `ListPlot3D`. This data set surface does not extend beyond `x^2 + y^2 == constant`, `x==0`, and `y==0`.

I can set polar mesh lines with `Norm[{#1, #2}] &`. Currently, I set radial mesh lines with `Arg[Complex[#2, #1]] &`. However, I would like to hard code the locations of the polar mesh lines to be at specific values of the parameter `constant` so I can use them to set a visual scale. I am not particularly savvy with *Mathematica* so please provide detail.

Code as requested:

```
RData = Import["out.dat"]

ListPlot3D[RData, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 500}, {0, 500}, {0, 0.065}}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Boxed -> False, 
 Axes -> {False, False, False}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["Energy (kJ/mol)", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 18], 
               Style["Energy (kJ/mol)", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 18],   
               Style["P(E)", Black, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 18]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 18}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Norm[{#1, #2}] & , Arg[Complex[#2, #1]] &}, Mesh -> {9, 8}, 
 LabelStyle -> Black, Ticks -> {Automatic, None, None}, MeshStyle -> Thick, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Thick
]
```

I would like polar mesh lines drawn every 50 units. Since I don't have control of the upper range of my data, it is difficult use the `Mesh -> {9, 8}` option to achieve what I am describing.

Best,
Eric

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Please provide further details on your surface, and show the code you have used so far. It will be much easier to help out that way.

Comment: You could extract the necessary range from your data, I suppose. Would it work for you if you used `Mesh -> Range[50, Max@Rdata[[All, 3]], 50]` to generate a list of values at which to generate mesh lines that goes from a minimum of 50 to a maximum value dictated by your data, every 50 units?

Comment: @MarcoB I am not sure if $z$-range is the problem, as a polar grid should not depend on that. I guess it is more that the `constant` maximum radius is the problem. Modifying your comment accordingly would give `Mesh -> {Range[50, Max[Norm[#] & /@ RData[[All, 1 ;; 2]]], 50], 
  Range[0, Pi/2, Pi/16]}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP never provided raw data to reproduce the problem.